# VSTS Build failing - Error : Web deployment task failed

Tags: asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, azure-devops

I have a build definition in Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online) to build an ASP.NET web application using an on-premise agent. The agent has VS2012 installed and all the other necessary prerequisites to assist in building the application. However, when running the build, it fails and outputs below error:

> C:\Program Files 
>   x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4021,2):
>   Error : Web deployment task failed. (**The .zip file package
>   'C:\BuildAgent\_work\1\a\' must be a file, not a directory.**)
>   Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.

I tried building the project on the agent machine using VS2012 and it builds fine. Also, I have defined following MSBuild parameters in the build definition which is same as my other builds that use a hosted agent:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

What could be the cause of this issue? Do I need to install anything extra?

Comment: Which task did it fail at? It seems that this failed during deployment, not the build

Answer (score 2):

You are using VS2012, you need to specify detail PackageLocation argument with .zip suffix ($(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\testWeb.zip). If you are using higher version of VS/MSBuild (e.g. vs 2015), a folder path is ok, it will adds [XXX].zip to the end of that path.